# Create JDBC realm on glassfish - wrong pass?

Tags: jdbc, glassfish-3

I've followed this tutorial http://blog.gamatam.com/2009/11/jdbc-realm-setup-with-glassfish-v3.html

**The problem is that I get login dialog again and again like pass is wrong** (and never page), but I clearly see values in DB. Pass is MD5 of the word 'admin'.

So how to debug it?

Here are the settings and printscreens: http://codepad.org/jHNRpAta

And here is web.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Constraint1</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>test</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <description/>
            <role-name>USER</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>security</realm-name>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description/>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

And here is glassfish-web.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>USER</role-name>
    <group-name>USER</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
    <group-name>ADMIN</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Comment: No one?

_______________